# How to put quanteda tokens into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, tokenize, quanteda

I've used quanteda to tokenize 10+ texts and the result looks like

```
text 1    [character]   word 1, word 2, word 3...  
text 2    [character]   word 1, word 2, word 3...  
...
```

The type of this file is 'tokens'. So I'd like to change it to a dataframe like:

```
id    content  
text1  word 1  
text1  word 2  
text1  word 3  
text2  word 1  
text2  word 2  
...
```

I've tried

```
data.frame(id = 1: length(the token file), content = unlist (the token file))
```

It doesn't work because of the different length of rows.
Could anyone help? Thank you!

Comment: Could you try `as.list()` or `as.list.tokens()` functions .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would go via `dfm` and `convert` to get where you are.

Since you didn't give an example, I will use a part of the `data_corpus_inaugural` corpus from quanteda.

```
library(quanteda)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# create tokens
toks <- data_corpus_inaugural %>%
  corpus_subset(Year > 1990) %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE)

# convert to data.frame via dfm
out <- convert(dfm(toks), to = "data.frame")

# pivot to get desired outcome
my_df <- out %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(!doc_id), names_to = "tokens", values_to = "freq")

my_df
# A tibble: 21,312 × 3
   doc_id       tokens    freq
   <chr>        <chr>     <dbl>
 1 1993-Clinton my            7
 2 1993-Clinton fellow        5
 3 1993-Clinton citizens      2
 4 1993-Clinton today        10
 5 1993-Clinton we           52
 6 1993-Clinton celebrate     3
 7 1993-Clinton the          89
 8 1993-Clinton mystery       1
 9 1993-Clinton of           46
10 1993-Clinton american      4
# … with 21,302 more rows
```

After this, you can drop the column freq as this contains the frequencies of the words, but you also need to filter out the words that have a frequency of 0 as these are the words in other texts that do not appear in this text.

```
my_df %>% 
  filter(freq != 0)
```

Now if you want to get the sentences you tokenized in the exact order back, you need to do things a bit differently. `dfm` rolls all the same words into one. This means all the "the"'s in the first text will appear as one item with a frequency count.

So to get the tokens in order form the tokens object you need to do something else. I will take the same tokens object as before, `toks`, then use `as.list` to get in into a named list, and from there via `sapply` into a named array with equal lengths so we can use `as_tibble` to create a data.frame and avoid the error you got about different row lengths. Later on I remove all the tokens that have an NA value as these are the additions to each text to make sure everything is of the same length.

```
tok_out <- as.list(toks)

# create named array of equal lengths
x <- sapply(tok_out, '[', seq(max(lengths(tok_out))))

my_df_via_toks <- x %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(), names_to = "text", values_to = "tokens") %>% 
  filter(!is.na(tokens)) %>%  # remove NA values of each text
  arrange(text)

# A tibble: 15,700 × 2
   text         tokens   
   <chr>        <chr>    
 1 1993-Clinton My       
 2 1993-Clinton fellow   
 3 1993-Clinton citizens 
 4 1993-Clinton today    
 5 1993-Clinton we       
 6 1993-Clinton celebrate
 7 1993-Clinton the      
 8 1993-Clinton mystery  
 9 1993-Clinton of       
10 1993-Clinton American 
# … with 15,690 more rows
```

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about the argument sapply(tok-out, '[', seq(max(lengths(tok_out)))? I am not sure if I understood the '[' seq(...) part.

Comment: @user19192947,  `[` is used for indexing (check `?\`[\`` for more info), in this case a list. the `seq` part checks the maximum length of all the lists and that number will be used as the index. Empty values, `NA`, are used on the index positions if there is no value . `sapply` simplifies the indexed lists to a data.frame. Another advantage of doing this is that it will use the names of the named list as column headers.